# "for _ dinner" vs "for A walk"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

Why do we say "to invite someone for _ dinner" without any article whereas in "to go for **a** walk" we use one?

Is there any general rule covering the cases or should they just be remembered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just idiomatic:

Meals. Generically:

invite someone to dinner and all the other meals, too. [breakfast,lunch, supper and tea]

You can use **for**, also. That is slightly different than: I was invited to **a dinner** when I was in Paris. The dinner was very formal. However, specifically,  you might say **a** instead of nothing: a dinner, a lunch when explaining it. Tea is a bit different. No "a tea" here.

Movement and transportation:

go for a drive, for a walk, for a spin, for a run, for a swim, for a ride (horses or bikes or motorbikes) = **as a generic idea for an activity**

The phrases works as one, though drives and walks are often used in the plural, too.

Comment: _A dinner_, as Lambie implies, is a formal occasion which includes the serving of a meal. It's much less common to hold a formal meal at breakfast- or teatime, though _a breakfast_ or _a tea_ are possible (in my opinion). If you invite someone _for dinner_, it could mean just to share in your normal family meal.

Comment: When I was in London, I was invited to a breakfast [or tea] for diplomats.